# Are transaction fees required now? Is there any way to avoid them?

Tags: client, e-wallet, blockchain.info, transaction-fees

I have been using blockchain.info's my wallet to perform transactions, one of the reason I liked it was because I could choose to not pay a transaction fee. But recently I noticed blockchain.info's interface has changed, there's no way to not include a transaction fee now? (or am I wrong about that?).

Was there a change in the Bitcoin protocol to require transaction fee? or are there still clients available that has the function of not paying a transaction fee?

Comment: For the web-based hybrid EWallet or for the Blockchain for Android / iOS mobile app?

Comment: The web version of blockchain wallet.

Comment: I am also looking at using this facility. But the application I intend to use it for - 0.0005btc is just far too much. I am looking at allowing people to do 0.001btc payments - surely this is a bit ridiculous? Can anyone assist with this? I understand that bitcoin was not designed for micropayments - but then how are people going to make this work in the real world?

Comment: Seriously they really got to stop demanding transaction fees. When bitcoin values go up, 0.0005 BTC will start to cost more and more. Imagine sending someone a $0.20 and being charged $0.30 for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Send Custom for full control over fees.

Click Send Money tab, then on the left menu under Transaction Type click Custom.

This URL might get you there.

- https://blockchain.info/wallet/login#send-custom

Comment: I have tried it, but it seems even if I put 0.0 fee at that screen, when I review the transaction, a 0.0005 BTC fee is still included.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Frugal option.  That way only the minimum (recommended) fee is included and only if the protocol rules require that you pay a fee.

Comment: What is the Frugal option? I'm trying to find out if there is any client that allow me to always avoid paying any fee, not even the "recommended fee". Are you saying the protocol now require a fee or else the transaction won't work?